# Georeferencing Webcam Image using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, georeferencing

I want to georeference pixels from a webcam image.

[image: nyharbor]

I have the camera location, and some control points of pixels to map coordinates.  I  am trying to figure out the math to do the translation.  I don't know the lower right/left map coordinates.

For the above image, I know the location of the camera 40.70286, -74.01404, 165m [17 State St, NYC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/17_State_Street).  How can I translate pixel coordinates to geocoordinates of a pixel.  I tried using ArcGIS Pro's georeference, but it doesn't seem to handle the horizon very well.

With ArcGIS Pro, my control points would be... (wish ArcGIS Pro would export map_x/map_y as latlon):

```
pixel_x     pixel_y     map_x           map_y
339.666308  -441.486654 -8239835.313964 4967183.046727
917.830637  -352.302926 -8242513.931035 4966531.862069
401.835739  -387.274793 -8240332.623448 4966441.313103
1046.993990 -351.920576 -8242890.206897 4966865.655172
433.863020  -374.742007 -8240599.172414 4966116.137931
115.142624  -470.434959 -8239236.689655 4967144.827586
54.149778   -364.465369 -8239849.655172 4965014.620690
80.573857   -313.712187 -8241915.409655 4954775.304828
192.402362  -312.360694 -8243484.936969 4954109.473474
704.019561  -320.165239 -8245496.584828 4962415.404138
1222.083443 -369.797452 -8242280.275862 4967672.827586
1123.011167 -342.695843 -8243750.862069 4966812.931035
```

Comment: Try searching the internet for the phrase "georeference oblique camera images"?